# Hacer uso de la api de gmail por medio de una cuenta de servicio desde el lado del servidor evitando la GUI de OAUTH2

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en python que usa el servicio SMPT para conectarse a una cuenta de gmail. Ese tipo de conexión está tipificada como un "Acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras" https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Para subsanar esto me he puesto con la tarea de actualizar mi app, usando la api de gmail y para la autenticación hacer uso de una clave privada generada a partir de una cuenta de servicio (sin usar G-Suit).

He creado una primera prueba de concepto y parece que conecta correctamente, pero al intentar obtener las labels de la cuenta de gmail obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.">
```

Recapitulo los pasos que he seguido para configurar mi cuenta de google:

1. Acceder a [Google Api Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) y habilitar el uso de la api de gmail por medio del botón que aparece en la parte de arriba: Habilitar apis y servicios
2. Acceder al apartado de credenciales, hacer click en el botón superior: "crear credenciales" y seleccionar **Cuenta de servicio**
3. Crear una cuenta de servicio y seguidamente generar una clave privada en formato json

Añado un pequeño fragmento de código con mi prueba de concepto y que me devuelve el error que comento en la parte superior:

```python
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build

    SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/home/user/keys/privatekey_from_service_account.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No tienes labels.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])
```